# Returning the full path to a Google Drive folder in Google Spreadsheets return permission error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have in my spreadsheet an URL of Google Drive folder,

E.g: `https...drive.google.com/a/_our-domain_/#folders/_my-folder-id_`

and i want to put a full path to another cell, so e.g. `/my-1stlevelfolder/second/parent/my-folder`

I have created the function, which does exactly what i want, but it works only in the editor. When I use the function in spreadsheets, it shows in the cell #ERROR and message, that i do not have permissions. I have allowed google drive in both Sources and developer console (but it worked even without it in script editor) and of course i have rights to see the content of the tested folder (and again, it worked in script editor)

```
  function getpath(url) {
    if (url == undefined) return;
    var names = [];
    var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(url.replace(/.*\//g,''));
    while (folder.getName() != "Root"){
      names.unshift(folder.getName());
      var parents = folder.getParents();
      var folder = parents[0];
    }
    var result = names.join().replace(/,/g,'/');
    return result
  }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this action when the function is executed from the spreadsheet, see the doc here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions?hl=fr#permissions

Answer (score 0):

Harold is right (of course^^), custom functions are very limited in what they can do... It is quite easy to build a workaround using an embedded script triggered by an installable onEdit trigger that will automatically fill the desired cells with the url related data as long as your sheet is structured in a way a script can understand.
If you want a more accurate answer you'll have to describe your sheet layout.